# Different tables and more CSS

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt, html-table

I have to adapt a XML and XSL file.
Usually there was the CSS just for one table in my XSL, but I want to have different tables classes to change their look.

In my XML file I call the tables:

```
<table class="first">....

<table class="second">....
```

May tables are in:

```
<component><section>
```

In my CSS in XLS I have predefined for all tables this:

```
.section_table {
  width: 100%;
}

.section_table tr td {
     margin-top: 0;
     margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

How can I adapt this code to make my tables look different?

I also found this code in my XSL file, which might be important for you:

```
<xsl:template match="n1:table/@*|n1:thead/@*|n1:tfoot/@*|n1:tbody/@*|n1:colgroup/@*|n1:col/@*|n1:tr/@*|n1:th/@*|n1:td/@*">
    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="n1:table">
  <xsl:variable name="numColumns">
        <xsl:value-of select="count(n1:thead/n1:tr/n1:th)"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <table class="section_table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><!--  numColumns="{$numColumns}" -->
    <xsl:apply-templates>
      <xsl:with-param name="numColumns" select="$numColumns" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    </table> 
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="n1:thead">
    <thead>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </thead>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="n1:tfoot">
  <xsl:param name="numColumns"/>
    <tfoot>
        <xsl:apply-templates>
      <xsl:with-param name="numColumns" select="$numColumns" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    </tfoot>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="n1:tbody">
    <tbody>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </tbody>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="n1:colgroup">
    <colgroup>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </colgroup>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="n1:col">
    <col>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </col>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="n1:tr[position() mod 2 = 1]">
  <xsl:param name="numColumns"/>
    <tr class="odd">
    <xsl:apply-templates>
      <xsl:with-param name="numColumns" select="$numColumns" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="n1:tr">
    <xsl:param name="numColumns"/>
    <tr class="even">
    <xsl:apply-templates>
      <xsl:with-param name="numColumns" select="$numColumns" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- table-heading processing -->
  <xsl:template match="n1:th">

   <!-- sum up all given widths -->
   <xsl:variable name="sum">
     <xsl:call-template name="sumgivenwidths">
       <xsl:with-param name="widths" select="../n1:th" />
     </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:variable>

   <!-- calculate table width -->
   <xsl:variable name="tablewidth">
     <xsl:call-template name="calctablewidth">
       <xsl:with-param name="widths" select="../n1:th" />
       <xsl:with-param name="sumgivenwidths" select="$sum" />
     </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:variable>

    <!-- width calculating -->
    <xsl:variable name="cwidth">
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="@styleCode != ''">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="substring-after(@styleCode, ':') &lt; 0">
          <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@styleCode, ':-')" />
        </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@styleCode, ':')" /> 
            </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>

        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="(100 - $sum) div count(../n1:th[not(@styleCode != '')])" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>

    <!-- 100 percent scaling -->
    <xsl:variable name="scalewidth" select="concat($cwidth * 100 div $tablewidth, '%')" />

    <!-- create th element -->
    <xsl:element name="th">
      <xsl:attribute name="width"><xsl:value-of select="$scalewidth"/></xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- recursive loop through all given widths -->
  <xsl:template name="sumgivenwidths">
    <xsl:param name="widths" />
    <xsl:param name="sum" select="0" />

    <xsl:variable name="current" select="$widths[1]" />
    <xsl:variable name="next" select="$widths[position()>1]" />
    <xsl:variable name="currentwidth">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="substring-after($current/@styleCode,'xELGA_colw:') != ''">
          <!-- absolute value -->
          <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="substring-after($current/@styleCode, 'xELGA_colw:') &lt; 0">
          <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($current/@styleCode, 'xELGA_colw:') * -1" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($current/@styleCode, 'xELGA_colw:')" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="0" />
        </xsl:otherwise> 
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not($next)">
        <xsl:value-of select="$currentwidth + $sum" />
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:call-template name="sumgivenwidths">
          <xsl:with-param name="widths" select="$next" />
          <xsl:with-param name="sum" select="$currentwidth + $sum" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- recursive calculation of table width -->
  <xsl:template name="calctablewidth">
    <xsl:param name="widths" />
    <xsl:param name="sumgivenwidths" />
    <xsl:param name="sum" select="0" />

    <xsl:variable name="current" select="$widths[1]" />
    <xsl:variable name="next" select="$widths[position()>1]" />
    <xsl:variable name="currentwidth">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="substring-after($current/@styleCode, 'xELGA_colw:') != ''">
          <!-- absolute value -->
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="substring-after($current/@styleCode, 'xELGA_colw:') &lt; 0">
              <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($current/@styleCode, 'xELGA_colw:') * -1" />              
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($current/@styleCode, 'xELGA_colw:')" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="(100 - $sumgivenwidths) div count(../n1:th[not(@styleCode != '')])" />
        </xsl:otherwise> 
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not($next)">
        <xsl:value-of select="$currentwidth + $sum" />
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:call-template name="calctablewidth">
          <xsl:with-param name="widths" select="$next" />
          <xsl:with-param name="sumgivenwidths" select="$sumgivenwidths" />
          <xsl:with-param name="sum" select="$currentwidth + $sum" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="n1:td">
  <!-- td-element ELGA stylecode processing -->
    <xsl:variable name="transform_smallcase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
    <xsl:variable name="transform_uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />

    <xsl:variable name="transformed_stylecode" select="translate(@styleCode, $transform_smallcase, $transform_uppercase)" />

    <xsl:variable name="tdStyleCode_Style">
      <xsl:if test="contains($transformed_stylecode, 'LRULE')">
        <xsl:text>text-align: left;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="contains($transformed_stylecode, 'RRULE')">
        <xsl:text>text-align: right;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="contains($transformed_stylecode, 'TOPRULE')">
        <xsl:text>vertical-align: top;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="contains($transformed_stylecode, 'BOTRULE')">
        <xsl:text>vertical-align: bottom;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="contains($transformed_stylecode, 'BOLD')">
        <xsl:text>font-weight: bold;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="contains($transformed_stylecode, 'UNDERLINE')">
        <xsl:text>text-decoration: underline</xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="contains($transformed_stylecode, 'ITALICS')">
        <xsl:text>font-style: italic;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="tdStyleCode_Class">
      <xsl:if test="contains($transformed_stylecode, 'EMPHASIS')">
        <xsl:text> smallcaps </xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>    
      <xsl:if test="contains($transformed_stylecode, 'XELGA_BLUE')">
        <xsl:text> xblue </xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="contains($transformed_stylecode, 'XELGA_RED')">
        <xsl:text> xred </xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:variable>
    <td style="{$tdStyleCode_Style}" class="{$tdStyleCode_Class}">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </td>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="n1:tfoot/*/n1:td">
  <xsl:param name="numColumns"/>
    <td colspan="{$numColumns}">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </td>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="n1:table/n1:caption">
    <span class="caption">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </span>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Your CSS is not related to your HTML (or XML) example, and you mention XSL three times but posted no XSL code. Please edit your question and explain your problem in more detail, with more code as well.

Comment: Its just my XML (HTML) and CSS (in XSL) important. What XSL code to you want to see?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add link to css file in the head section (of html part) in the xsl file

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my_style.css"/>
        </head>
    </html>
    .
    .
    .
</xsl:tempelate>
```

Add in css file "my_style.css"

```
.first {
  width: 100%;
}

.second tr td {
     margin-top: 0;
     margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

I have added a file.

Try to edit your files like [this](http://www.fileswap.com/dl/lULx4p0m9O/).

Comment: hi thank you, but its correctly linked :) i just need help to make the css statements for the table classes. It confuses me, that the predefined table css starts with ".section_table". How should I start my css statements for my two tabel classes?

Comment: If you could post your all three files, maybe I can look into it. Without looking at exact element names and class names I can't tell much.

Comment: I have 2 files: The XML and XSL. The CSS is in the XSL in the head position! And the important code is in the first post. Thats everything...

Comment: I added a code to the first comment! This might be important!